# Wordpress - Auto replace class names in HTML, CSS & JS

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a plugin or easy method to mass-rename my classes/id's. Does anyone know if such a plugin?

I found that 'hide my wp' can replace classes in HTML, but it doesn't edit the css/js.

Thanks!

Comment: Find & replace function in your IDE would do what you want

Comment: Use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-code-editor/.